# Error in .BAT file R Script

Tags: r, batch-file, scheduler

I have a .bat file as follows. task.bat

```
@echo off
R CMD BATCH C:\Users\Raghavan\Desktop\MyTask.R
```

The file needs to run an R script. The following is the R script.

```
 A<-read.csv("C:\Users\Raghavan\Desktop\A.csv")
 write.csv(A, file = "B.csv")
```

The R script runs by itself. However, when I try running it through the .bat file or through windows scheduler, the script fails to run. I have tried many sites.I request someoen to see if this error can be fixed. Most likely, the error is in the .bat file

Comment: In all probability, it's a matter of where the current directory is. Try inserting, after the `@echo off`, a line `cd C:\wherever\the directory\containing\the r executable\is located` to change the current directory when `R` is run. Replace the directory name with wherever the directory is from which you normally run R.

Comment: @Magoo, current directory as in current working directory. I Will make the change

Comment: I have made the necessary changes. I have set the working directory to the desktop, placed the two files on the desktop and run the script. The .bat file opens but the script doesn't run. I have reset the working directory as per your request

Comment: This works. But it needs to be used in conjunction with a changed drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I run my R files with the following command inside of the .bat script:

```
@echo Off
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.2\bin\R.exe" CMD BATCH --vanilla --slave "C:\File.R"
```

Define the full paths to executable R and to the file that you wanna run. Hope this helps.

See also `?BATCH` and [this resource](https://github.com/gastonstat/tutorial-R-noninteractive/blob/master/02-batch-mode.Rmd) on arguments of R CMD BATCH.

Comment: This works. Also I was helped by shifting the files to D drive. C was write protected.

Answer (score 0):

I made the following edits to the code.

```
  @ echo off
  "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.2\bin\R.exe"  R CMD BATCH "D:\Newfolder\task1.R"
```

The files were then shifted to the D drive. This resulted in the code working.